# Putting separate ranges into 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to get a 2D array of size `[x][3]` filled. `X` is just the size of the sheet (number of rows) and there are 3 columns which I am interested in. The columns are not near each other, for instance `arr[i][0]` should be filled from column AA, `arr[i][1]` should come from column K, and `arr[i][2]` needs to be from columns L.

I tried assigning it the following way, but got an error in the array value assignment.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
Sub SOC_work()
'Trying to sort each of the disciplines further, by Stage of Construction

Dim ar_SOC() As Variant
Dim int_NumRows As Long
Dim i_counter As Long
Dim j_Counter As Long
Dim lite As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("AVEVA_PBOM_PARTS").Select


'Redimension the array size to the amount of parts in the PBOM
int_NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1
ReDim ar_SOC(int_NumRows, 3)

'now assignt he range into the array space
lite = Range("AA2", Range("AA2").End(xlDown))


ar_SOC[][1]=lite



End Sub
```

Is there any way to do this without looping through the entire column?

Comment: Fill 3 separate 2D arrays and then loop to combine them into one. Looping through arrays are much faster than through cells in a range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the comments, you can fill three 2-D arrays. You can then populate a fourth array from the three arrays, like below.

```
Sub populateArray()
    Dim arrColOne() As Variant, arrColTwo() As Variant, arrColThree() As Variant
    Dim arrAllData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    arrColOne = Range("A2:A" & lrow(1)) 'amend column number
    arrColTwo = Range("D2:D" & lrow(4))
    arrColThree = Range("G2:G" & lrow(7))

    ReDim arrAllData(1 To UBound(arrColOne, 1), 2) As Variant
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrColOne, 1)
        arrAllData(i, 0) = arrColOne(i, 1)
        arrAllData(i, 1) = arrColTwo(i, 1)
        arrAllData(i, 2) = arrColThree(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function lrow(colNum As Integer) As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

The above will require all 3 columns to be the same length (otherwise populating the last array will not work); this is due to the fourth array being redimensioned to contain the number of elements contained in the first array.

> Testing with 250,000 rows of data, the fourth array populated in 0.43 seconds.

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I've been looking for in order to dump 4 non-contingent ranges (columns), run a countif on all the rows, then highlight the necessary (duplicate) rows. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How lenient are you with the array you get in return? I can get you a `Array(col)(row)`-style array, without having to loop to get it, if that works. Note that's not `Array(col, row)`, by the way. It's a single-dimensional array of columns, with each element containing a single-dimensional array of row values. If you're okay with that, you can do this:

```
Dim a(1 To 3)
a(1) = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("AA2:AA10")), 1, 0)
a(2) = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("K2:K10"  )), 1, 0)
a(3) = WorksheetFunction.Index(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("L2:L10"  )), 1, 0)
```

Then you could access your array items like so:

```
Debug.Print UBound(a)     ' Number of columns (3)
Debug.Print UBound(a(1))  ' Number of rows in column 1
Debug.Print a(1)(3)       ' Value of column 1 (AA), row 3
```

The `Index()` function can return a 1D array but only in the *rows* direction. So, you need to combine it with `Transpose()` to return a 1D column array. That's all the code above is doing.

Comment: I don't think I can use it that way in this case, but it's a usefull idea, so I'm saving your code for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about an array of arrays?

```
Sub NoLoop()
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range
Dim Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant, Arr3() As Variant

Dim LR As Long
LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
LR3 = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

Set R1 = Range(Cells(1, "AA"), Cells(LR1, "AA"))
Set R2 = Range(Cells(1, "K"), Cells(LR2, "K"))
Set R3 = Range(Cells(1, "L"), Cells(LR3, "L"))

Arr1 = R1.Value
Arr2 = R2.Value
Arr3 = R3.Value

ArrArr = Array(Arr1, Arr2, Arr3)

End Sub
```

With this you can call your values using:

```
MyVal = ArrArr(0)(1,1)
MyVal = ArrArr(0)(2,1)
MyVal = ArrArr(1)(1,1)
```

Where the first number is for the array (starts from 0 and ends with 2) and the second number is for row/cell of the range used to fill array.
The third number is always 1 (because adding a range to an array returns a bidimensional array)

With this code you can also have different dimensions for each column so to save memory.

Comment: This is what I do in my answer, too. You can actually get rid of that 2D array, however (and the need to always specify the `1` column index for it), with a combination of `Index()` and `Transpose()`.

Comment: @Bond Sorry, I was writing while you answered. I'm not a pro and my goal is just to reciprocate the help received.

Comment: Absolutely. Wasn't trying to imply that you shouldn't have posted this. Just wanted to high-five for both coming up with similar solutions!